# DropdownButtonFormField gives Error when try to display String

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, widget

I want to make DropdownButtonFormField that shows cities like this:

```
final List<String> cities = ['London', 'New York', 'Paris', 'Shanghahai', 'Tokyo'];

String _currentCity;

DropdownButtonFormField(
            value: _currentCity ?? ' ',
            decoration: textInputDecoration,
            items: cities.map((city) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: city,
                child: Text('$city City '),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentCity = val ),
          ),
```

But when I try to show these Strings I get red screen error :
[image]

and If I changed the Strings inside the List to numbers it works well:

```
 final List<String> cities = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with it although I use List of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set _currentCity for default value?

```
String _currentCity = 'London';
```